# What is the meaning of abbreviation ynaq in nethack?

Tags: nethack

I am new to Nethack, English is not my first language, and the first game screen shows:

```
NetHack, Copyright 1985-2018
         By Stichting Mathematisch Centrum and M. Stephenson.
         Version 3.6.1 Unix, revised Sep 16 16:35:42 2018.
         See license for details.


Shall I pick a character's race, role, gender and alignment for you? [ynaq]
```

Looking at each letter in the option list, I presume that they mean:

- y: yes
- n: no
- a: **unknown**
- q: quit or exit

What does the "a" option do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Choosing `a` means no takebacks are allowed for this choice.

The explanation can be found in the game's [code](https://github.com/NetHack/NetHack). For example, [lines 544 through 548 of `/win/tty/wintty.c`](https://github.com/NetHack/NetHack/blob/61b86b88383921af902a41c2999f4255af224371/win/tty/wintty.c#L545-L548) (windows version, console menu) state:

```
    /* this prompt string ends in "[ynaq]?":
       y - game picks role,&c then asks player to confirm;
       n - player manually chooses via menu selections;
       a - like 'y', but skips confirmation and starts game;
       q - quit
     */
```

so it appears that choosing the `a` option does the same as choosing the `y` option (randomize your role), but does not allow you to confirm or cancel if you got a combination you don't want to play, instead it will immediately start the game.

Looking a bit further at [line 950](https://github.com/NetHack/NetHack/blob/61b86b88383921af902a41c2999f4255af224371/win/tty/wintty.c#L950):

```
getconfirmation = (picksomething && pick4u != 'a' && !flags.randomall);
```

The boolean `getconfirmation` is always false if `pick4u` (containing the player's choice) is set to `a`. Thus the program will not run the code asking for confirmation, instead leaving the function and presumably going on to setup the game.

Comment: I don't know if I'd call that "ironman mode" so much as "I'm feeling lucky mode." In my experience, "ironman" usually means the game's difficulty is increased by changing game mechanics.

Comment: I guess "a" means "yes to **a**ll",  like in many cli utilites (e.g. powershell)

Comment: @enkryptor Considering also the line of source code mentioned, my guess would be that it stands for "auto(matic)".

Comment: @scohe001I only know "Ironman" to mean "You can't save/load except when quitting, so no takebacks". But I guess there's multiple meanings to it :)

Comment: @Erik: Various games seem to use it to mean some combination of "you can't quit without saving or save without quitting", "you can't interact with other players" (i.e. solo play, for games that normally include trading with other players and the like), and/or "character death is permanent".

Comment: A bit of a stretch, but a similar set of responses is accepted when using the confirm flag with the `:s` command in `vim`; there `a` is explicitly documented as "to substitute this and all remaining matches". Basically, you turn off step-by-step confirmation of a set of choices and accept all the remaining suggestions.

Comment: Echoing @enkryptor here: considering Nethack’s origins and its native environment, it’s almost-certainly echoing various *nix utilities that use the same options. In addition to `vim` that chepner mentions, `git` comes to mind immediately, though the `--patch` option in `git` that uses `ynaq` has quite a few other options besides those four.

Comment: Nethack is always in "ironman mode" in the sense that death is permanent and you don't get to keep old saves. Though the game probably predates the phrase, so it doesn't feel right to call it that. Automatically choosing the character doesn't really even make it any harder, since at the beginning, you can always just restart, and there's nothing the game can do to stop you... I don't think it's much of a voluntary challenge either, since you might get a strong class as well as a weak one. So yeah, I'd call it "auto" mode too.

Answer (score 18):

It's hard to find information on this, and I've often wondered it myself, but it seems to stand for "all". Even the Nethack Wiki doesn't define "ynaq".

In the case of item accumulation:

- Typing `y`    picks up that item, and displays the
  next.
- Typing `n`    displays the next item.
- Typing `a`    picks up that item, and all remaining items of the named
  types. The program will not allow the player to pick up any item which is too heavy.
- Typing `q`    aborts the command.

In the case of starting a new game, it would make **all** relevant choices for you so the game can begin in earnest.

Do note that when pressing `q` your character [will be deleted](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Quit). It's best to save instead using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

References:

https://thekill08.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/hack-and-nethack-the-software-distillery/
ftp://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/oldies/apple2/unsorted/Hack.txt

Comment: It seems to me that "a" probably stands for "**auto**" (as in "automatic"), which fits the context you describe somewhat better than "all".

Comment: @Will It’s definitely “all,” since this usage is common in the *nix world and is equivalent to simply using `y` in response to all prompts.

Comment: The `a` stands for "always".